# Flutter IAP In app purchase payment not received

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, applepay, google-pay

I have configured IAP and create a subscription, everything go fine in test mode, after I created a production release, the users when explore the subscription and purchase it, they got an email with:
`Thank you. This is a test subscription. It will recur according to this schedule. You have not been charged.`

Could you please tell me why this happened? And please provide me with any suggestion.